# Applet drawing in response to user input

Tags: java, graphics, applet, drawing, paint

I want the applet to draw a circle when the user hit on the jButton1, but the circle draws it self Spontaneously not in response to user input. i tried many methods i even searched for two days on the net for an answer but i couldn't find one. this is what i reached today.

```
package project002;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JApplet;

/**
 *
 * @author B_HITMAN
 */

public class NewApplet extends JApplet {

private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private void initComponents() {

    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jButton1.setText("jButton1");

    jButton2.setText("jButton2");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(21, 21, 21)
            .addComponent(jButton1)
            .addGap(41, 41, 41)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addContainerGap(192, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(30, 30, 30)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addComponent(jButton2))
            .addContainerGap(247, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

}
public void init() {


                initComponents();
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            Graphics g = getGraphics();
                update(g);
        }
    });       
}
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(140, 140, 20, 20);
}


}
```

Comment: `Graphics g = getGraphics();`  This is the wrong way to go about doing custom graphics.  See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for working examples.  As an aside, what code were you looking at that gave you that idea?  Just as a tip, stick to developing code based in a `JFrame` for the moment.  It is much easier to develop and debug.  See [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/) for details.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you, i'll check your links. i got the idea from [here](http://www.scs.ryerson.ca/mes/courses/cps530/programs/threads/Repaint/index.html) but i guess i implemented it wrong.

Comment: *"..i got the idea from here.."*  That seems to have been written back in the days of AWT, but it is still full of questionable bits of advice (even for using AWT).  Stick to the Oracle tutorials for the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the init and paint method with the following will do

```
public void init() {
    initComponents();
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            showCircle();
        }
    });
}

private boolean circleIsVisible = false; 
private void showCircle() {
    circleIsVisible = true;
    repaint();
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    if (circleIsVisible) {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(140, 140, 20, 20);
    }
}
```

The paint method is called when the applet first show. So you have check if the circle should be drawn or not before drawing it. Then make the applet repaint as in 'showCircle' when the state is changed.

Hope this helps.